# Import ESRI raster .gdb to QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

Can anyone tell me if and how you can import raster data from Esri geodatabase folder into QGIS v 3.16.11?

Comment: Two ways currently - 1. use ArcGIS to export the raster to another format, like a GeoTIFF or 2. compile and use [Arc Raster Rescue](https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue)

Answer (score 3):

GDAL and QGIS do not support FGDB rasters but there are plans to develop such raster driver. I believe this page is best for following the current situation https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/173.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, QGIS does not yet support FGDB rasters. As an alternative, you could convert the FGDB rasters to another format, such as .tif, using Arc (assuming that you have access to Arc!).  Then load the .tif into QGIS.